# Is there a way to overwrite underscores in MATLAB/Psychtoolbox?

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox, experimental-design

I'm doing an experiment in Psychtoolbox and I want to make a stem completion task. So, I will show my participants incomplete words such as for 'apple' 'app'. And I want to write it as 'app _ _'. The problem occurs when I try to do with my code, I got a word 'app _ _ le'. But, I want to make underscore disappear, when any letter is typed. So, I would really appreciate, if someone has a solution about it.

I'm using MATLAB 2016a, so ignore function does not work for me. Also, when I am using `replace`, it replaces it before underscore occurs. I tried to use `strrep` and `regexprep`. But, i don't want to have any space between letters.

For echoing the participant input to screen I'm using

```
Ask(window,excelfile,black,[],'GetChar','center','center');
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], including the things you tried which didn't work, and why they didn't produce the result you wanted

Comment: You can use a solution like the following code pattern: `A = 'apple';B = 'app__';idx = find(B == '_', 1);B(idx) = A(idx);disp(B);idx = find(B == '_', 1);B(idx) = A(idx);disp(B)`